# .NET BUG? SplitContainer Split move selects all text of contained controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some nested SplitContainers and there is one undesired behaviour happening. Every time the splitter moves, the controls get their text selected (the text gets highlighted), specially the ComboBoxes.

I don't know why thios happens. The problem is fairly easy to reproduce. You just need to:

1. Create the form.
2. A put a split container in it.
3. Add a ComboBox with some items.
4. Anchor the left and right sides of the ComboBox.
5. Compile
6. Move the Splitter

You will see that the ComboBox will have its text highlighted.

How can I prevent this from happening? Or at least, remove the highlight from the ComboBoxes?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an age-old bug in the Windows native combobox control.  Yes, it selects the text when it gets the WM_SIZE message.  This is specific to DropDownStyle = DropDown.

This is a possible workaround:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyComboBox : ComboBox {
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
        if (!this.Focused && this.DropDownStyle == ComboBoxStyle.DropDown) {
            this.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
        base.OnResize(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: just what I needed, thanks! I'll post the VB version, in case anyone like me took over a VB project and has no way out, lol.

Answer (score 0):

The VB version of @hansPassant's answer, as I needed it today. For anyone who took over a VB project and has no way out, this might be helpful:

To modify the Resize event of a specific control (here `ComboBox1`):

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Resize
    Dim curr_combo = TryCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)

    If ((Not curr_combo.Focused) And curr_combo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown) Then
        curr_combo.SelectionLength = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

To create a generic event, you can attach to many `ComboBox`s:

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim curr_combo = TryCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)

    If ((Not curr_combo.Focused) And curr_combo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown) Then
        curr_combo.SelectionLength = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

then add it to one of your ComboBox controls like this:

```vb
AddHandler my_combo.Resize, AddressOf ComboBox_Resize
```

Or to all of them like this:

```vb
For Each obj As Object In Me.Controls()
    Dim combo = TryCast(obj, ComboBox)
    If TypeOf combo Is ComboBox Then
        AddHandler combo.Resize, AddressOf ComboBox_Resize
    End If
Next
```